# Create new pandas dataframe from existing dataframe, using row numbers from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have one dataframe like this, let's call it df1:

```
       Column1   Column2   Column3  
1258   .51       .38       .12

2674   .76       .21       .45

3098   .89       .34       .19

6012   .91       .78       .67
```

Then I also have another dataframe, let's call it df2, with about 10000 rows.

```
       a    b   c   d
0      0    1   0   0  
1      1    1   1   0
2      0    0   0   1
3      0    0   1   1
...
10000  1    1   0   1
```

Is there a way I can create a new dataframe from df2 with the row numbers from df1? So the output dataframe would be like this:

```
      a   b   c   d
1258  0   1   0   1
2674  1   0   0   1
3098  0   1   1   1
6012  1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this is `loc`

```
df2.loc[df1.index]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2.reindex(index=df1.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
df2[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
```